# How does a user style an Element Directive in AngularJS without knowing how it composes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Firstly, sorry for my poor English.

I'm learning AngularJS recently and I found that many of AngularJS's concept are very advanced especially the Directive. It's much like the `Shadow DOM` or `Web Components`, and even better.

But I came up with a question about the directive(We just talk about the directives with the restrict of 'E' and have a template which will replace or insert into the directive here.)

That is: How does a directive user(not the directive's writer) style a directive without knowing how it conforms? How could the user ensure that his style do not overwrite the directive's style?

As you know, directive is a reusable component, and much of the times, the user isn't the writer of the directives, he just use it.

Let's say a case here:
a directive written in HTML like this:

`<myDirective></myDiective>`

my be replaced by the below Emmet expression(or even more complex):

`div>h1+ul>li*8>a+img`

Here comes the question, how does the user style this myDirective? The user does not know the DOM structure of the directive.

1. Should he inspect the directive in the devtools when it is replaced by the template and then style the replaced DOM?
2. Or he should go check the source code of the directive?
3. If the user style the directive, how should he avoid the overwrite?
4. Or the directive writer should style the directive using it's namespace?

**I think this is a big problem that AngularJS Directive should have to face.**

Notice that this is difference with the `Shadow DOM` or the `Web Components` because the latter's style can not overwrited by the user, it's in an isolate style scope.

Comment: I'm guessing that that user in your case is the designer writing the css. you can show him your templates. If you wont use `replace : true` he would also be able to style each directive specifically using a selector to the directive name. Plus, before you decide to use `restrict : 'E'` I suggest reading the IE guidelines.

Comment: This issue isn't specific to Angular directives, but to all pre-web-component Javascript plugins. Web components are mentioned in the future of Angular at https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Gv-dvU-yy6WY7SiNJ9QRo9XayPS6N2jtgWezdRpoI04/mobilepresent?pli=1#slide=id.ge845cf80_037 although doesn't give much detail.

Answer (score 0):

To style an html chunk, whatever code can be, you must see in action at least one time. Grab the markup, and then proceed to style it. You can see the code most of the times in the template property. (Most of the times, some others the markup is a composition). 
It would be highly desirable that the markup doesn´t contain specific classes so when you - the user - start styling it, don´t have to face any styling issues.

If you are the directive code owner, then the things should be pretty straightforward. Even more, you can specify an url to the templateUrl property that just contains your html code for that given directive.

I would also encourage you to apply the OOCSS technique for styling reusable objects. And as a suggestion avoid the selectors that you have specified in your post, they don´t perform very well.

Regarding your questions:

1 and 2, yes, they´re valid options.
3 and 4, investigate OOCSS technique, and CSS Specificity concept.

Hope that this helps,

Best Regards.